# How to use trig identities to simplify an expression with variables.

Tags: trigonometry

I have tried simplifying this expression for over an hour with no success. Given a and b are constants how does one simplify.

$\sqrt{3}a(\sin{\pi/b})+\sqrt{3}b(\sin(\pi/a))$

Since we do not know a and b, is this impossible

Comment: In general, linear combinations of sine waves can always be simplified to a single sine wave with a different phase shift. In your case, the formula wouldn't look very "neat," but it can be done.

Comment: See here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities#Linear_combinations

Comment: The values under the trig functions are different - thus the above seems not relevant.

Answer (score 0):

*A possible idea (I hope)*

Consider 
$$F=\sqrt 3\left(a \sin \left(\frac{\pi }{b}\right)+b \sin \left(\frac{\pi }{a}\right)\right)$$ Now, let $a=\frac \pi A$ and $b=\frac \pi B$ to get
$$F=\pi\sqrt 3\left(\frac{\sin (A)}{B}+\frac{\sin (B)}{A}  \right)$$ Now, let $B=A+C$ to get
$$F=\frac {\pi \sqrt 3 }{A(A+C)}\left( A \sin (A)+(A+C) \sin (A+C)\right)$$ and use what is written in the [arbitrary phase shift](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities#Linear_combinations) section.

It would be quite messy, I guess but it seems to be workable.